# db error, axios get method returns (TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser') 500

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, token

I am trying get a list of data associated with logged in user, I am using vuejs, axios and drf. corsheader activated on both sides.
I succeeded getting auth token, change the state and save it in the local storage.
the code is failing in getting user specified data, here is my codes:

## views.py

```
class blogsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return CodeNote.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    serializer_class = blogsSerializer
```

## myblogs.vue

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
const API_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
export default {
  name: "myBlogs",
  data: () => ({
    blogs: []
  }),
  mounted() {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("TOKEN_STORAGE_KEY");
    console.log(token);
    axios
      .get(API_URL + "blogs/mylist", {
        headers: { Authorization: "Token " + token }
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.blogs = response;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

the console shows the token successfully. I am not sure if I am doing the right request, or the problem is with filtering.

Answer (score 2):

There are few checks you need to do.

- Check If you have add Default Authentication  class  in REST Framework Setting. Implement Whichever you wish to have.

```py
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
                'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
                    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
                    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
                    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
                )
    }
```

- In Your View You must Add permission_classes. If you want to provide access to only authenticated users.

```py
  class blogsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = CodeNote.objects.all()
        serializer_class = blogsSerializer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated
```

- If your want to provide access to both authenticated and normal users. 
  you must check if user is authenticated and process accordingly.

```py
 def get_queryset(self):
     if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return CodeNote.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
     return []
```

- Check If Token you are sending from local storage from frontend actually exists in Database.
- All in One

```py
    class blogsListView(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = CodeNote.objects.all()
        serializer_class = blogsSerializer
        # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

        def get_queryset(self):
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                return CodeNote.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
            return []
```

Comment: It is working in normal backend api view, but in the front end not. I will try your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: @omeraiman. Sure please check updated answer. Let me know if it helps. Thank you

Comment: I am getting empty response. I think the problem is in the request from the front end using axios. I am not sure if I am sending the token right attached with the request.

Comment: Can you show error? May be the token is expired one or wrong one. Check if token you are sending exists in database. ie token from local storage with database

Answer (score 0):

it worked out, thank you @bkwan for help, I add rest framework settings, and edited the axios request like this:

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
                'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':(
                    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
                    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
                    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
                )
    }
```

```
 def get_queryset(self):
     if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return CodeNote.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
     return []
```

```
axios
      .get(API_URL + "blogs/mylist", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Token ${token}` }
      })
```